# Different designs/layouts and save them in database and replace with html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want different designs/layouts and save them in database 
and replace `{renderaction1}` with `@{Html.RenderAction("Index","render1");}` 
and `{renderaction2}` with `@{Html.RenderAction("Index","render1");}` (can be more/less or types).

The reason,  I want to have different design for every customer with a dynamic content. For example
customer1 wants to have 2 select lists and 1 comment field
customer2 wants to have 1 select list and 1 chart. 
Any tip how to make it smart and good?

From database

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Text1</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{renderaction1}</td>
    <td>{renderaction2}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After replace

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Text1</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@{Html.RenderAction("Index","render1");} </td>
    <td>@{Html.RenderAction("Index","render2");}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use Regular expression to match and replace.

Comment: Will the helpers work if I just insert them with replace?

Comment: If you're pulling the entire layout from a database, you'll have to forgo traditional view rendering. Take a look at Razor Engine: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine. So, you'll run a regex over the string from the DB to replace what needs to be replace, parse the view dynamically using the template, and then return the whole thing as your action result instead of return `View` like normal.

Comment: Yes it is what im looking for I think, thanks Chris